# Modificacion en Excel desde Java Exlipse Con poi

Tags: java, excel, eclipse

Necesito Ayuda, ¿alguien sabe porque me da error `.getWorkbook()` ? ni siquiera puedo ejecutarlo ,sino que me marca en el código directamente. Me dice:

> The method getWorkbook(File) is undefined for the type XSSFWorkbook

Este es el fragmento de código:

```
package Excel;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FillPatternType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;   
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;    
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;    
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Antes_Del_Traslado_Excel {

 private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("mx.com.hash.newexcel.Antes_Del_Traslado_Excel");

 public Antes_Del_Traslado_Excel() {

     try {

         File Excel = new File("Traslados.xlsx");

         XSSFWorkbook Libro=XSSFWorkbook.getWorkbook(Excel);

         XSSFSheet Hoja1= Libro.getSheetAt(0);

         XSSFRow Fila=Hoja1.createRow(0);

         XSSFCell Celda=Fila.createCell(2);

         Celda.setCellValue("Prueba");

         FileOutputStream Salid = new FileOutputStream(Excel);

         Libro.write(Salid);

         Salid.close();

     }catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

         LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Archivo no localizable en sistema de archivos");

     }catch (IOException ex) {

         LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error de entrada/salida");

     }

 }

}
```

Yo lo que estoy intentando con ese código es agregar datos a un excel ya existente.

PD: Probé con `Workbook Libro=Workbook.getWorkbook(Excel);` pero también me da el mismo error

Comment: que tutorial estas usando? podrias proveer el link? por que respecto a la documentacion no existe ese motodo , solo el getWorkbookType. https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html @GuillermoAndria

Comment: aaah,puede ser que este mal el tutorial que vi , porque me llamo la atención porque era el único que lo usaba, Disculpe yo no se mucho de esto , yo estoy intentando aprender ,Disculpe mi ignorancia.

Comment: yo antes usaba                                                                                           XSSFWorkbook workbook=new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);                                              Pero esta forma me pruducia error "Sheet index (0) is out of range (no sheets)" y pense que era porque me creaba otro Workbook y en ese Workbook no había ningún sheets pero e intentado de todo pero no consigo solucionarlo,estaría muy agradecido si alguien me propria ayudar

Comment: Okay para no escribirlo de nuevo y demas, este link te puede ayudar https://www.ecodeup.com/como-escribir-y-leer-archivos-microsoft-excel-en-java/ si te ayuda permitime saberlo, sino veremos que errores tienes... @GuillermoAndria

Comment: Muchísimas Gracias pero intentando y intentando pude solucionarlo.Les dejo el link por si alguien tiene el mismo problema que tenia yo.                           https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288753/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-sheet-index-0-i